# Heroku deployment fails due to sqlite3 in rails5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, sqlite

The problem is frustrating enough. I tried all present solutions. And let me describe those and my unresolved situations.

My Gemfile Looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin' 
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'
```

## Attempted solution 1:

Replace

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

with

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then

```
bundle install 
git add .
git commit -am"Update Gemfile"
git push heroku master
```

This solution doesn't work for me. Heroku still tries to install sqlite3.

## Attempted solution 2:

Remove `sqlite3` from the Gemfile and use `postgresql` in everywhere(`development`,`test`, `production`)

So, I installed postgres and did the necessary setups to run my project locally with postgres. It works fine.

My `database.yml` looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

This solution doesn't work for me. Heroku still tries to install `sqlite3`.

## Attempted solution 3:

So, people suggested I have some gems that depends on sqlite3. Well, in attempted solution 2, my Gemfile and Gemlock has no trace of sqlite3.

Heroku still tries to install `sqlite3`.

So, people suggested to show the `Gem dependency`

Here is my`Gem dependency` connected to sqlite3

```
Gem orm_adapter-0.5.0
  activerecord (>= 3.2.15, development)
  bson_ext (>= 1.3.0, development)
  bundler (>= 1.0.0, development)
  datamapper (>= 1.0, development)
  dm-active_model (>= 1.0, development)
  dm-sqlite-adapter (>= 1.0, development)
  git (>= 1.2.5, development)
  mongo_mapper (~> 0.11.0, development)
  mongoid (~> 2.8.0, development)
  rake (>= 0.8.7, development)
  rspec (>= 2.4.0, development)
  sqlite3 (>= 1.3.2, development)  <---
  yard (>= 0.6.0, development)


Gem sass-rails-5.0.6
  railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8)
  sprockets-rails (< 4.0, >= 2.0)
  sqlite3 (>= 0, development)   <---
  tilt (< 3, >= 1.1)
```

Now the suggestion is to remove those Gems that depends on `sqlite3` .
But `Devise` depends on  `orm_adapter`. Then, do I have to remove `Devise` too?  That sounds too ugly to be true. Then there is sass-rails. sass-rails says it needs sqlite3 on development environment only. I'm stuck here.

At this point, Any new suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes I ran `bundle install` . Look at my attempt-1 .  I'm using pg locally. I'm also adding `database.yml` for convenience .

Comment: Definitely you should remove the gem 'sqlite3'. The database.yml doesn't matter on heroku. My suggestion is to look at your gemfile.lock and search for sqlite3 there, if it's there remove it.

Comment: Look at my attempt-2. There is no trace of sqlite3 in Gemfile and Gemlock.

Comment: Can you paste the output of heroku when doing `git push`?

Comment: @Gaston, `git push` shows the age old sqlite.h missing problem.

Comment: I was just able to fix the problem!  My problem was I was doing all of my changes on a non-master branch. It took me a while to figure out that heroku by default gets the push from master branch, even if I'm checked out on a non-master branch. I was able to solve my issue with both Attempt-1 & 2 . A sample comand `git push -f heroku local_branch:master`